# Rails - Name can't be blank error when the input isn't blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I get an error of 'Name can't be blank' and "Name only allows letters, numbers and '-'" when trying to update a name. This was working fine but I have just gone through it again while writing a test for it and realise it isn't working anymore, I can't figure out why or what has changed to break it.

**Categories controller**

```
def update
  if @category.update category_params
    redirect_to new_guide_category_item_path(@guide, @category)
    flash[:info] = "Updated successfully"
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

private

def category_params
  params.require(:category).permit(:name, :template)        
end
```

**edit.html.erb**

```
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
      .....
 <%= form_for([@guide, @category], url: guide_category_path) do |f| %>


   <%= f.label :name, "Category name" %>
   <%= f.text_field :name %>

   <%= f.label :template, "Template" %>    
   <%= f.text_area :template, { :id => 'edit' } %>

   <%= f.submit "Save", :value => "Save Template"  %>

<% end %>
```

**model**

```
 validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }, uniqueness: { scope:  :guide_id, case_sensitive: false },
  exclusion: { in: %w( guide guides category categories item items page pages post posts tag tags key keys item key item keys item-key item-keys item_key item_keys mod moderator mods moderators admin admins), message: "%{value} cant be taken." },
  format: { with: /\A[a-zA-Z0-9 -]+\z/, message: "only allows letters, numbers, spaces and '-'" }
```

**routes**

```
resources :guides do
    resources :categories,    only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update] do
    end
end
```

Anyone have an idea of what might be going wrong?

**Edit added log output**

```
Started PATCH "/guides/ghj/categories/ijijij" for ::1 at 2016-02-11 14:08:04 +1100
Processing by CategoriesController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"IqiUJ8wF8ZY4t8f91+t4aOMc9xenx/F2beKjKs9GY7JzLD6ZgPYDY1ueC2s+OIDL+PjROVtMe2+GvgYdan1CDQ==", "category"=>{"name"=>"ijijijddd", "template"=>""}, "commit"=>"Save Template", "guide_id"=>"ghj", "id"=>"ijijij"}
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  [1m[36mGuide Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  "guides".* FROM "guides" WHERE "guides"."slug" = ?  ORDER BY "guides"."id" ASC LIMIT 1[0m  [["slug", "ghj"]]
  [1m[35mCategory Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."slug" = ?  ORDER BY "categories"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["slug", "ijijij"]]
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "category_item_keys"."name" FROM "category_item_keys" WHERE "category_item_keys"."category_id" = ?[0m  [["category_id", 6]]
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "check_category_item_keys"."name" FROM "check_category_item_keys" WHERE "check_category_item_keys"."category_id" = ?  [["category_id", 6]]
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "category_item_keys"."name" FROM "category_item_keys" WHERE "category_item_keys"."category_id" = ? AND "category_item_keys"."key_type" = ?[0m  [["category_id", 6], ["key_type", 1]]
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "category_item_keys"."name" FROM "category_item_keys" WHERE "category_item_keys"."category_id" = ? AND "category_item_keys"."key_type" = ?  [["category_id", 6], ["key_type", 2]]
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "category_item_keys"."name" FROM "category_item_keys" WHERE "category_item_keys"."category_id" = ? AND "category_item_keys"."key_type" = ?[0m  [["category_id", 6], ["key_type", 3]]
  [1m[35mGameModsRelationship Exists (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "game_mods_relationships" WHERE "game_mods_relationships"."user_id" = ? AND "game_mods_relationships"."category_id" = 3 LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 1]]
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mbegin transaction[0m
  [1m[35mCategoryItemKey Exists (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "category_item_keys" WHERE ("category_item_keys"."name" IS NULL AND "category_item_keys"."guide_id" IS NULL) LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mCategory Exists (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "categories" WHERE (LOWER("categories"."name") = LOWER('ijijijddd') AND "categories"."id" != 6 AND "categories"."guide_id" = 3) LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  rollback transaction
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "game_mods_relationships" WHERE "game_mods_relationships"."user_id" = ? AND "game_mods_relationships"."category_id" = 3 LIMIT 1[0m  [["user_id", 1]]
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered categories/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (5.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_header.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 157ms (Views: 145.1ms | ActiveRecord: 1.1ms)`
```

Comment: Can you paste your log when you try to update a category?

Comment: @JCorcuera https://docs.google.com/document/d/1u9yr5vkeuKmTd9clOJb7LID7PDOIqRyy50KeL-CZrWM/edit?usp=sharing put it in this google doc.

Comment: Please don't make people jump through hoops in order to help you. Edit your question to include the log output.

Comment: 1. You really need to read a Rails tutorial before continuing  2. Simplify "form_for", there's no need for the url to be explicitly passed.  3. Why are you adding an explicit id for your textarea ("edit")?  4. The last thing it checks from the database is the uniqueness, which isn't surprising.  How do you get the errors that you're showing at the top?

Comment: 2. yes in this case the url isn't needed, but I have a lot of forms not in their associated views so its just become habit now to add the url to all forms. 3. I have a WYSIWYG editor on the text area, the editor works on inputs with the id 'edit'. 4. `<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>` is just above the form sorry I forgot to add it in the post.

Comment: 3. You should be using a class, then, not an id.  What happens if you have two of them on one form?  It would help to also name is something more descriptive than "edit".  Always think of the guy who has to look at this in 5 years and figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add error_messages helper tag in the partial. That handles all error messages and show it properly.

Comment: There is one in the view but not directly in the form.

Comment: it should be in the form or have access to instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your database has an existing record with the same name. Try inputting a unique name in. In your model, it is checking for :uniqueness.